# Calculate product affinity in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a sales dataset where each row contains Account ID and one product they purchased. One Account ID can purchase a few products which means there might be more than one row for the same Account ID.

In Excel, I calculated for each product, what's the top 50 products that sold the most with it. for example, there are 2000 accounts who bought product A and also bought product B and there are a total of 5000 accounts that bought product A. So there are 2000 overlapping accounts and 3000 non-overlapping accounts for A and B.

The problem is that **those calculations are not based on individual account level**, it's the sum of all accounts. If I want to find out who are those 3000 non-overlapping accounts, I can't do it in excel because it already exceeds the capability of excel. I have 25000+ accounts and 700+ products, so just imagine the number of combinations.

I want to do it in SQL, but I have no idea how. So far I have this pivot table in SQL Server 2012. The very left column is Account ID and the columns on the right are products. Each product is one column. The table will show for each distinct account ID, what product they purchased. It will be either blank or 1. Below is the matrix I copied from Excel, sorry it looks a little messy.

```
Account ID          Product A   Product B   Product C   Product D   Product E   Product F   Product G
0014000000aSrFoAAK      1               1        1                      
0014000000aSsteAAC                          
0014000000aStJBAA0          1           1        1
0014000000aSvsqAAC          1           1                  
0014000000aSxtSAAS      1               
0014000000aSxV7AAK              1           
0014000000aSxV8AAK                          
0014000000aSxV9AAK                  1       
0014000000aSymRAAS                      1   
0014000000aSzUuAAK          1   1           
0014000000aT8BtAAK          1           1   1
0014000000aT8o0AAC      1   1       1   1   
0014000000aT8yyAAC              1       1   
0014000000aT8yzAAC                          
0014000000aT8zRAAS          1               
0014000000aT8zSAAS                          
0014000000aTAkVAAW              1           
0014000000aTBC4AAO          1       1       
0014000000aTgnOAAS      1                   
0014000000aTgrpAAC          1       1       
0014000000aTijRAAS                      1   1
0014000000aTJOGAA4          1               
0014000000aTNRPAA4      1           1       1
```

Comment: Hi sqlbeginner, welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for bringing in some example data. I've formatted it as *fixed width* so you can align it like a table, but you will have to fix the spacing yourself so that the numbers are in the correct columns. It can also help to include the `CREATE TABLE` statement that defines your table, especially if this pivoted result is from a query on a table with an unpivoted structure.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Thanks AirThomas! Your editing helped a lot!

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response, Tiago Goddard. My question is how to write sql query to do the calculation. If you read my original question, you will see i have purchase history for each account, and I'm trying to calculate for each combination of 2 products, say product A and product B,what are the non-overlapping accounts? by non-overlapping accounts, i mean who bought product A, but not product B. Please let me know if i still didn't myself clear...